# How to break a string into two parts

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I am parsing a string from my plist and trying to break it into two parts to display them in two or three lines as per the break.

```
NSArray * parts = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]; // this text is coming from plist.
int nthLine = 0;
for(NSString *str in parts)
{

CGRect outerFrame = CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x, frame1.origin.y + 45*nthLine, frame1.size.width, 45);

SFNDoorStyledView * question = [[SFNDoorStyledView alloc]initWithFrame:outerFrame];
question.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
question.tag = 2;
[question drawString:text inRect:CGRectMake(0,0,500,150) usingFontNamed:@"Futura-Bold" size:40.0 lineSpacing:40.0 kernValue:-3.0 color:@"#7d7066"];
[self.view addSubview:question];
}
nthLine = nthLine +1;
```

Comment: So, what's your question? Are you getting an error?

Comment: What is happening when you run this code and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: The string which i am trying to break is "When do you want to retire" and i want it to break after 'you' So i converted it as "When do you \n want to retire?" such that 'when do you' appears in first line and rest of it display in next. BUt with this this code everything including \n is coming in one line

Comment: Why are you trying to seperate the string to achieve this? Cant you just use the \n syntax in you string as is? If your string contains \n your call to NSLog will automaticly put everything after \n on a new line when its printing.

Comment: I am doing that only. I am putting \n into my string and then trying to separate it through \n to diplay it in two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually plist saves your string as a text. SO if you enter \n it takes it as a text and not as linebreak. In spite of doing it i break the string in plist only. For ex: if you have a string , What is your current income monthly? and you want to break it from income. Then you can write What is your and then press alt+enter and enter the text in new line.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful what \n means in different contexts.

In this context

```
NSArray * parts = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

\n is interpreted as a newline character.

In your plist \n will be the actual characters \ and n

You could use option-enter to add the newline character to the plist and then use your code above or better yet:

```
NSArray * parts = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Or if you want to use this custom '\n' delimiter you could use

```
NSArray * parts = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\n"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `UILabel` to hold your text, which you can size dynamically based on the string itself. No need to include `\n` in the string. Just size/constrain your label to the width you need, and the height will be calculated for you based on other attributes like font and font size. Here's a representative snippet.

```
// Size the label based on the font and actual text
UILabel *l = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 300, 50)] autorelease];
l.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
l.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
l.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
l.numberOfLines = 0; // Allow for as many lines as needed
l.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [l.text sizeWithFont:l.font 
       constrainedToSize:constraintSize 
       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
CGRect frame = l.frame;
frame.size = labelSize;
// Center it
frame.origin.x = floor((320.0 - labelSize.width) / 2.0);
l.frame = frame;

[v addSubview:l];
```

Comment: I can't. i have to use this View to display the content as we are using CoreText.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the line separator is actually `\n`. It could also be `\r`. So using `componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r\n"` might help.